# How can I send the 'Customer Completed' email to the customer's email in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I'm currently using WordPress, WooCommerce, and Dokan. I have a requirement to resend the "Customer Completed" email to the seller instead of the customer. Unfortunately, the code I wrote is still sending the email to the customer.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$email_class = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'];

             // Send the email to seller
             $vendor_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_dokan_vendor_id', true );
             if ( $vendor_id ) {
                 $seller_email = dokan()->vendor->get( $vendor_id )->get_email();
                 if ( $seller_email ) {
                     $email_class->recipient = $seller_email;
                     $email_class->trigger($order_id);
                 }
             }
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me in resolving this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the recipient is being set inside the trigger(), so `$email_class->recipient = $seller_email;` will be overwritten. you need to use recipient filter hook instead.

It should be like that:

```
function filter_completed_order_recipient( $recipient, $order, $email ) {
    $vendor_id = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_dokan_vendor_id', true );
    if ( $vendor_id ) {
        $seller_email = dokan()->vendor->get( $vendor_id )->get_email();
        if ( $seller_email ) {
            $recipient = $seller_email;
        }
    }
    return $recipient;
}

$email_class = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'];

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'filter_completed_order_recipient', 100, 3 );

$email_class->trigger( $order_id );

remove_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'filter_completed_order_recipient', 100 );
```